# Path Validation - My RegEx is matching leading spaces in directory names and I can't fix it

Tags: regex, powershell, validation, path

I'm back again with more RegEx shenanigans.

I had what I thought was a perfect windows path validation expression.

Here it is at Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/BertHu/6

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|\\?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*$
```

Breakdown:

```
# (?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|     # Drive
# \\?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)                              # Relative path
# (?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*                              # Folder
# [^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*                                     # File
```

The issue I'm having now, is that the expression is matching paths with leading spaces in directories.

Example: `C:\ Leading Space\ Shouldnt Match` is matching.

I tried adding `[^\s]` to the folder portion of the expression:

`(?:[^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*`

But that only invalidates a leading space in the *first* path segment:

`C:\ LeadingSpace\ShouldntMatch` Doesn't match (Good)

`C:\LeadingSpace\ ShouldntMatch` Matches incorrectly (Bad)

I think the problem lies here:

[image: Regex]

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Sorry for all the RegEx questions!

Comment: Building such a complex regex is hard. How about making a function that tests the path in several steps instead? First check drive letter/unc path/registry provider, then see there aren't extra slashes, split on slashes and check each remaining part?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends what the exact rules are, if I take your *regex101* script, as basis, I would say:

File, Folder and Relative Folder, are more or less the same (if you ignore the no-capture group and the Backslashes):

```
 \\?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?
(?:[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*
[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*
```

So there are three potenital places, where folders could start with a leading space.

You could add a `[^\s]` infront of all of them like this

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|\\?([^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n])+\\?)(?:[^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*([^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n])*$
```

<s>I saved the modified regex101 https://regex101.com/r/Pd3lcR/1</s>

Now it should work, at least for my limited testcases, and information about the restriction.

***Btw.:** I don't know what your use case is, but this regex is pretty long for a smiple matching and filename capture, may be there is a more readable way(for non regex people).*

**Update:**

to fix the introduced Bug, I have to prevent the Share option matching with the relative path, by preventing a double slash with `(?!\\)`

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]:|\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+)\\|\\?((?!\\)[^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n])+\\?)(?:[^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*([^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n])*$
```

<s>here the updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/RMVkTC/3</s>

**Update (Version 2):**

I rewrote the regex to the way I would create it. It is not perfectly optimized(short), but this way it is easier to test/bugfix.
The RegExp is exactly 3 parts, piped together:

- Drive + path + folder/file: `(^[a-z]:\\([^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\)*[^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+$)`
- relativepath + folder/file: `(^(\.?\.?\\[^\\])*([^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+\\?)*$)`
- Share + folder/file: `(^\\\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\[a-z0-9_.$●-]+\\([^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]*\\?)*$)`

like this, if you have to change something for one edge case, it is more contained and easy to adapt.

here the updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/Qxj3Ni/1

Comment: Getting there, thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately with your new additions `\\192.168.0.1\INVALID SHARE\` matches when it shouldn't. The share component of a UNC path can't have spaces.

Comment: That is exactly, why regex is not perfect if you are trying to match many different cases in on expression. It will get longer, and some edge Case might stop working. I will check, what caused this.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I can always find a way to check for leading spaces after the regex validation happens - basically splitting the operation into multiple steps so it isn't so complex and hard to understand. But I am fairly determined to get this regex working. To be honest, if you break the expression down into it's constituent parts, it's not as complex as it might seem.

Comment: @Jay did my answer solve the problem? If so please accept it, if not what is missing?

Comment: It's still accepting values that are incorrect. Like:

"●●●●●●●●●●●●●●"
and 
C:\Leading Space\Shouldnt Match \Shouldnt Match\test.exe

It's a nice improvement though, thank you. I gave you an up-vote, but the actual problem hasn't completely been solved yet.

Comment: @Jay thanks. I didn't know that it, didn't solve your problem. I just had your question as working basis. But if you really want to to 100% check for valid path, as mentioned before I would **not** do it in one big regex, because it would get really long _( I would use the builtin function `'Test-Path' with the parameter `-IsValid`)_ . btw.: '●●●●●●●●●●●●●●' is a valid path under windows, it is a relative path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Your solution is awesome! But I found a bug in the ReEx.

`C:\User\va lid` is NOT matching when it should.

`C:\To ols\ico ns\to ki-tori.svg` is NOT matching when it should.

Basically if there is a space in the filename after the final \ - the whole thing gets invalidated. I think it has something to do with the second capturing group:

`([^\s][^\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n])*`

I'm sure your time is limited. If you can possibly find a way to fix this edge case, I would be overwhelmingly grateful.

Comment: @Jay I updated my answer, although I change the expression, to make it easier to alter/manage.